# Data storage requirement per country and how to accomplish

Tags: mysql, database, cakephp, database-design, data-storage

We are US-based and have a SaaS web app. One of our clients is in Canada and requires any personal data collected be stored only in Canada.

Is there a best-practice or standard way to handle this type of situation?

Thoughts so far (none of which area ideal):

- Move the 'orders' table to a different Canada-based database server, and set it as the database for the 'Order' model.  (But would that restrict us from doing JOINS...etc?)
- Keep an entire second database server with a complete copy of the database in Canada, and use that for their app.  (but this would be a pain when we want to update the database, make table changes, manage servers in general...etc)

I'm not incredibly knowledgeable about servers, so pardon if i used the wrong terminology anywhere in this question.

Comment: See this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11684956/i-need-to-join-table-from-other-database-and-sometimes-other-server

Comment: Very interesting, Kai - thanks!  Will leave my question up in case there are any CakePHP specific solutions or alternate solutions, but - I have never heard of Federated tables before.